# how to detect online users with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using devise in rails 5.1.4, I want to display or send notifications to the users that this user is online with time a go,  or this user isn't online since time a go. how can I detect online users. My devise scop is Users also.

Comment: You need to read the documentation: [Devise Documentation - Controller filters and helpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers). That will help.

Comment: OK thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Use websockets (actioncable) and subscribe user to channel. If they are signed in, you can find any of their information. I can send you a code sample, if needed. 
update:

app/channels/messages_channel.rb

```
class MessagesChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    unless current_user.blank?
        stream_from "messages_auth_users"
    end
  end
end
```

assets/js/channel/messages.coffee

```
//= require action_cable
@App = {}
App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer('/cable')

$(window).ready ->
  App.messages = App.cable.subscriptions.create({
      channel: 'MessagesChannel'
    },
    received: (data) ->
      console.log ('!!!!!');
      $('.no_messages').remove()
    renderMessage: (data) ->
      $('.message-div').html(data.text)
  )
  return
```

and somewhere in controller or jobs to send data to websocket

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast "messages_authuser",
  text: 'Your text here',
  time: Time.now, any_another_nash: 'value'
```

Comment: OK little code will be very useful to me seen that it's my first time to use ruby on rails,  it means that I am a new on the framework

Comment: make upd, read some tutorials about action cable and another one about devise and then combine them